Backup database in SQL Server 2012 and restore this backup in SQL Server 2014
First what I do is to check consistency of database in SQL Server 2012:
CHECKDB (DATABASE1)

And it is ok, no errors and warnings.
Next I do FULL backup and restore it on another machine with has SQL Server 2014
using SQL Server Management Studio with WITH REPLACE option.
However after I run
CHECKDB (DATABASE1)

I receive consistency errors messages:
Msg 8939, Level 16, State 98, Line 1
Table error: Object ID 293576084, index ID 67, partition ID 72057594074628096, alloc unit ID 72057594126598144 (type In-row data), page (1:5589561). Test (IS_OFF (BUF_IOERR, pBUF->bstat)) failed. Values are 133129 and -4.
Msg 8928, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Object ID 293576084, index ID 67, partition ID 72057594074628096, alloc unit ID 72057594126598144 (type In-row data): Page (1:5589561) could not be processed.  See other errors for details.
Msg 8976, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Table error: Object ID 293576084, index ID 67, partition ID 72057594074628096, alloc unit ID 72057594126598144 (type In-row data). Page (1:5589561) was not seen in the scan although its parent (1:5580238) and previous (1:5589560) refer to it. Check any previous errors.
Msg 8978, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Table error: Object ID 293576084, index ID 67, partition ID 72057594074628096, alloc unit ID 72057594126598144 (type In-row data). Page (1:5589562) is missing a reference from previous page (1:5589561). Possible chain linkage problem.
Msg 8939, Level 16, State 98, Line 1
Table error: Object ID 293576084, index ID 1, partition ID 72057594073645056, alloc unit ID 72057594125615104 (type In-row data), page (1:21142097). Test (IS_OFF (BUF_IOERR, pBUF->bstat)) failed. Values are 133129 and -4.
Msg 8928, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Object ID 293576084, index ID 1, partition ID 72057594073645056, alloc unit ID 72057594125615104 (type In-row data): Page (1:21142097) could not be processed.  See other errors for details.
Msg 8976, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Table error: Object ID 293576084, index ID 1, partition ID 72057594073645056, alloc unit ID 72057594125615104 (type In-row data). Page (1:21142097) was not seen in the scan although its parent (1:21112030) and previous (1:21142096) refer to it. Check any previous errors.
Msg 8978, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Table error: Object ID 293576084, index ID 1, partition ID 72057594073645056, alloc unit ID 72057594125615104 (type In-row data). Page (1:21142098) is missing a reference from previous page (1:21142097). Possible chain linkage problem.
CHECKDB found 0 allocation errors and 8 consistency errors in table 'TABLE1' (object ID 293576084).
CHECKDB found 0 allocation errors and 8 consistency errors in database 'DATABASE1'.
repair_allow_data_loss is the minimum repair level for the errors found by DBCC CHECKDB (DATABASE1).

Am I doing something wrong with backup restoration?

Done. I reviewed my questions and added accepted where I accepted.


Your destination disk can be damaged. 2. The table in question may even not exist at the time of your dbcc check and be created later, during a backup. Did you check your source database AFTER taking a backup?


Yes, source database is still ok. destination disk is not damaged. Nothing change during backup.

By the way, if your original database has no problem why do you execute dbcc checkdb with REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS???

I'm sorry, on source database I run CHECKDB (DATABASE1) i wrongly pasted, I cannot edit it now, since post was moved from stack overflow

I corrected your first command on the source database, on your destination did you first run simple dbcc checkdb or started with REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS?

on destination db first I run simple dbcc checkdb and this is also for correction in post, because result errors show after simple  dbcc checkdb

Are both instances on the latest build? I hope you are aware both these versions are now out of support.

WITH REPLACE isn't guaranteed to "fully" overwrite the target DB. Try restoring to either another server entirely, or try restoring without using WITH REPLACE (i.e. drop the database you're planning on overwriting before starting your restore).

@Dan What do you mean by saying "WITH REPLACE isn't guaranteed to "fully" overwrite the target DB"? Do you want to say that if some index in the original db has 1000 pages from 101000 to page 102000 that in destination it will be on differnt pages or what?
